# STL istream header error on Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

When I try to compile using the iostream header, Code::Blocks opens the istream header and shows the following error message:

error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class std::basic_ostream'

It worked fine when I first downloaded Code::Blocks so my best guess is that I unintentionally altered this file and now it won't work.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Code::Blocks but the error persisted.

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Didi you uninstall and reinstall *the compiler* you were using with Code::Blocks?

Comment: Great, thanks Mike